# Evaluation of log(1 + large number) without overflow

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

In the middle of some involved computations, I came across the following expression:
$$f(x,y) = \ln (\cosh x + \sinh x\tanh y)$$

where $x,y$ are real numbers. I need to evaluate $f(x,y)$ over a wide range of values of $x,y$. In particular, $x,y$ can get very large (positive or negative). In this case $\sinh x,\tanh y$ may overflow, although the logarithm remains reasonable.

What numerical tricks can I use to evaluate $f(x,y)$ without risk overflow/underflow?

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps using the series expansions? (It may be hard to simplify into something nice, though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

$$f (x,y)=$$
$$\ln (\cosh (x))+\ln (1+\tanh (x)\tanh (y)) $$

with

$$\ln (\cosh (x))=\ln (\frac {e^x+e^{-x}}{2}) $$

$$=\ln (e^x\frac {1+e^{-2x}}{2}) $$
$$=x-\ln (2)+\ln (1+e^{-2x}) $$
$$\approx x-\ln (2)+e^{-2x} $$
for large values of $x$.

Comment: Assuming $x>0$, the last approximation can be made with some very simple bounds:
$$\ln(2)e^{-2x}<\ln(1+e^{-2x})<e^{-2x}$$

Comment: I am accepting this answer, since I already have a good implementation of $\log(1 + e^x)$ (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/vignettes/log1mexp-note.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

$-1 < \tanh(y) < 1$, so that shouldn't overflow if computed with a good algorithm.

$$ f(x,y) = \cases{x + \ln\left(\frac{1+\exp(-2x)}{2} + \frac{1-\exp(-2x)}{2} \tanh(y)\right) & if $x \ge 0$\cr
-x + \ln \left(\frac{1+ \exp(2x)}{2} - \frac{1 - \exp(2x)}{2} \tanh(y)\right) & if $x < 0$\cr} $$

Answer (score 0):

Many computer libraries have a *log1p* routine that uses a series to compute $\ln(1+x)$ for small $x$.  This can help when used with the other answers.  (If only, say, to let the computer do the thinking at the point of the $\approx$ sign in Salahamam Fatima's answer.)